# Añadir columna recién computada a un archivo csv en Python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Tengo una función en python que genera un `DataFrame` con 3 columnas, después guardo el `DataFrame` usando pandas con el código `.to_csv` uso el `mode='a'` para que no me sobre escriba los datos anteriores. Sin embargo cuando abro el documento final me acomoda todo en 3 columnas, una bajo la otra. Lo que quiero es acomodar las nuevas columnas al lado para poder manejar mejor el archivo.

Mi archivo luce así:

```
dot  lake     mock
1      42    11.914558
2      41    42.446977
3      40    89.188668
dot  lake     mock    
1      42    226.266513
2      41    317.768887
```

Y quiero que quede así:

```
dot  lake      mock        dot    lake     mock 
0      42     11.914558.    0.     42.   226.266513
1      41     42.446977.    1.     41.   317.768887
2      40     89.188668     2.     40
```

El coding que uso para guardar y generar el archivo csv es el siguiente:

```
Resultados.to_csv('/Users/Computer1/Desktop/Examples/resultados.csv', sep=',',mode='a',)
```

Gracias por sus ideas.

Comment: Si he entendido bién, en cada llamada a la función lo que haces es computar y generar una nueva columna `mock`. Puedes añadir columnas `mock` sin problemas al dataframe. No obstante, no deben tener el mismo nombre de encabezado, esto es confuso además de que el encabezado puede ser usado como clave de un diccionario por Pandas y las claves no pueden estar repetidas. Si no te importa tener una estructura del tipo   `dot      lake     mock_0     mock_1      mock_2      ...`  se puede hacer sin muchos problemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente se pudo grabar usando una estrategia como la que propuso [FjSevilla](http://FjSevilla), primero generé el archivo justo en la dirección donde se va a trabajar y una vez creado el archivo se puede abrir, escribir, guardar y volver hacer las veces que sean. El código para genera el archivo pandas es:

```
msd.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/SMT analysis codes/MSD_2.72.csv', sep=',',mode='a', index=False)
```

Después simplemente se define el valor de la variable que resulta de aplicar la función, se abre el archivo que se creo previamente, se concatena en el `axis=1` y se vuelve a guardar. he aquí el código:

```
b = Resultados
a = pd.read_csv('Resultados.csv')
c = pd.concat ([a,b],axis=1, ignore_index=True)
c.to_csv('/Users/Computer/Desktop/SMT analysis codes/MSD_2.4.csv', sep=',', index=False)
```

Tal vez no es bonito, pero funciona muy bien!

Answer (score 2):

Si agregas información al dataframe sin modificar las columnas hay dos formas de salvar con `to_csv`

```
Resultados.to_csv('/Users/Computer1/Desktop/Examples/resultados.csv', sep=',',mode='a',)
```

cuya salida sería, como bien dijiste:

```
dot  lake     mock
1      42    11.914558
2      41    42.446977
3      40    89.188668
dot  lake     mock    
1      42    226.266513
2      41    317.768887
```

O bien

```
Resultados.to_csv('/Users/Computer1/Desktop/Examples/resultados.csv', sep=',',mode='a', header=False)
```

cuya salida sería:

```
dot  lake     mock
1      42    11.914558
2      41    42.446977
3      40    89.188668
1      42    226.266513
2      41    317.768887
```

Lo que estás buscando no creo que tengas forma de hacerlo a menos que modifiques el `dataframe` y los nuevos valores vayan a nuevas columnas, pero entiendo que eso no tiene mucho sentido.

Comment: Oh ya veo, tiene sentido. Y con el archivo con forma de 3 columnas y los encabezados como separadores habría una forma de modificarlo después para que quede en la forma deseada?

Comment: Puedes agregar columnas al csv cargando el csv en memoria mediante `read_csv`, añadir las columnas y sobreescribir el archivo. Como dice Patricio esto no tiene demasiado sentido. Vas a terminar con multitud de columnas con el mismo encabezado, esto a la hora de manejar los datos complica sin necesidad el asunto. Si quieres diferenciar los datos por cada append podrías crear una cuarta columna que asocie un valor a cada append, aplicando un filtro sobre esta columna puedes obtener los datos de cada append de forma simple. ¿Cúal es la razón de necesitar los datos con esa estructura?

Comment: Para mi estaria perfecto ese arreglo con el mismo encabezado, porque solo me voy a quedar con la ultima columna y a promediar entre filas y graficar directamente. Entonces puede usar append?